# why print none for some lines

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

When i run this code to  this page  ( https://www.baiscopelk.com/tv-series/dark ) it works fine.Why is this happening

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
page = requests.get("https://www.baiscopelk.com/tv-series/game-of-thrones/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
column = []
    
for tr in soup.find("table" , class_="aligncenter").find_all("tr") :
        
   for links in tr.find_all('td')[0]:
       try:
          print(links.get("href"))
       except:
          print("error")
```

output

```
error
None
None
None
None
None
None
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=15124
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=15614
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=16099
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=16524
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=17179
```

Comment: Because `links.get("href")` returns `None` sometimes.

Comment: Please don't put tags into the title, that's what tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you some of those `<td>` tags do not have any `href` attributes. Would it be better to look for `<a>` tags and work off those?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
    
page = requests.get("https://www.baiscopelk.com/tv-series/game-of-thrones/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    
rows = []
trs = soup.find("table" , class_="aligncenter").find_all("tr")
for idx, tr in enumerate(trs):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    if idx == 0:
        columns = [td.text.strip() for td in tds]
    else:
        row = [td.find('a')['href'] if td.find('a') else td.text for td in tds]
        rows.append(row)
        
got_dict = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns).to_dict('list')
for k, v in got_dict.items():
    v = [x for x in v if x != None and x != '']
    got_dict[k] = v



for k, v in got_dict.items():
    print(k)
    for episode in v:
        print(episode)
```

**Output:**

```
S-1
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=12604
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=13014
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=13473
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=14579
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=14927
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=15124
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=15614
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=16099
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=16524
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=17179
S-2
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=23230
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=23545
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=24533
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=24921
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=24997
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=25038
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=25781
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=28397
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=28391
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=28566
S-3
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=24696
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=24900
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=25169
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=25732
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=26145
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=27598
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=27745
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=27755
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=27851
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=28046
S-4
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e01-two-swords-with-sinhala-sub/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e02-the-lion-and-the-rose-sinhalasub/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e03-breaker-of-chains-with-sinhalasub/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e04-oathkeeper-with-sinhalasub/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e05-first-of-his-name-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e06-the-laws-of-gods-and-men-with-sinhalasubs/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e07-mockingbird-with-sinhala-sub/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e08-the-mountain-and-the-viper-with-sinhala-sub/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e09-the-watchers-on-the-wall-with-sinhala-sub/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s4e10-the-children-with-sinhalasubs/
S-5
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e00-a-day-in-the-life-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e01-the-wars-to-come-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e02-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e03-high-sparrow-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e04-sons-of-the-harpy-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e05-kill-the-boy-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e06-unbowed-unbent-unbroken-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e07-the-gift-18-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e08-hardhome-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e09-the-dance-of-dragons-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s5e10-mothers-mercy-with-sinhala-subtitle/
S-6
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e01-the-red-woman-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e02-home-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e03-oathbreaker-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e04-book-of-the-stranger-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e05-the-door-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e06-blood-of-my-blood-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e07-the-broken-man-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e08-no-one-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e09-battle-of-the-bastards-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s6e10-the-winds-of-winter-with-sinhala-subtitle/
S-7
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s7e01-dragonstone-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s7e02-stormborn-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s7e03-the-queens-justice-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s7e04-the-spoils-of-war-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s7e05-eastwatch-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s7e06-beyond-the-wall-with-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=86872
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-conquest-and-rebellion-history-special-sinhala-subtitle/
S-8
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=110676
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=110912
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=111149
https://www.baiscopelk.com/game-of-thrones-s8e04-the-last-of-the-starks-sinhala-subtitle/
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=111941
https://www.baiscopelk.com/?p=112316
```

Comment: i want print links season by season : (